# google calendar sync token expire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api, google-api-ruby-client

hi i am trying to sync google calendar with my local calendar

my current setup works like this

i login via google and get my primary calendar events and store locally and i also save the sync token google provide at the last page.

so i have created a channel to watch calendar and it sends me notifications each time there is a change in calendar but what i want is to get the changed data if i send request again it just says token is expired how can i work around this.

i am using ruby on rails and google api gem

thank you

Comment: Are you getting 410 error when you use the sync token? if "yes" then the client should clear its storage and perform a full synchronization without any syncToken. Here is the link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync

Comment: Notifications only tell you that there was a change. For retrieving the changed data, you need to use the sync token you got at the last events.list() request.

Answer (score 0):

Access tokens expire.  You need to save the refresh token after authorization is first granted so that you can ask for new access tokens when making requests to the API.  I wrote a detailed blog post about it here: http://www.geekytidbits.com/google-calendar-api-from-ruby/

For example:

```
#First time authorization
auth_client.code = "authorization code goes here"
auth_client.fetch_access_token!
#Save auth_client.refresh_token now!

#Subsequent requests
auth_client.refresh_token = #grab refresh token from where you saved it
auth_client.fetch_access_token!
#You should now have a fresh access token
```